# How can I use javascript or jQuery to make this table fill available width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fluid-layout

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvygQ/

How can I stretch out a table to use the entire width and height the fluid-width container allows, while preserving the fixed header and scrolling tbody?

Look at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvygQ/) for how this works currently.  I'd like the same functionality but at full width and height.  HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery solutions are welcome!

[image: table fluid width height]

(original credit for scrolling fixed header tables to [CSSBakery](http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/12/css-scrolling-tables-with-fixed.html), thanks!)

HTML:

```
<div class="fluid-width-and-height">
  <div class="scrollableContainer">
    <div class="scrollingArea">
        <table class="cruises scrollable">
          <thead>
                <tr>
              <th class="name"><div>Name</div></th>
              <th class="operator"><div>Operator</div></th>
              <th class="began"><div>Began operation</div></th>
              <th class="tonnage"><div>Tonnage</div></th>
              <th class="status"><div>Status</div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                      <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Seabourne Sun</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Seabourn Cruise Line</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>1988</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Ended service in 2002, currently operating as Prinsendam</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Adventures of the Seas</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2001</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>138,000</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Oceanic Independence</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>American Hawaiian Cruises / American Global Line</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>1974</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>23,719</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Named formerly (1951-1974) and subsequently renamed (1982-2006) the Independence, renamed the Oceanic (2006), sold for scrap in 2008 but remains in mothballs</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Cunard Ambassador</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Cunard Line</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>1972</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>14,160</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Burnt 1974, rebuilt into a livestock carrier, renamed Linda Clausen, later Procyon, Raslan. Scrapped 1984 after a second fire.</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Aegean Beauty</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Voyages to Antiquity</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>1973</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>11,563</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Formerly Aegean Dolphin and Aegean I. Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Serenade of the Seas</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2003</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>90,090</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Queen Elizabeth 2</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Cunard Line</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>1969</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>70,327</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Left fleet in November 2008</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Queen Elizabeth</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Cunard Line</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2010</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>92,000</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Regent Sea</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Regency Cruises</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>1957</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Began operation in 1957 as the Gripsholm (II) for Swedish America Line. Ended operation when Regency went bankrupt in 1995. Was to be converted to a casino ship, but later marked for scrap. Prior to scrapping, was looted by pirates, then sank in heavy seas in 2001.</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Allure of the Seas</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2010</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>225,000</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Starts service in December 2010</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Amadea</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Phoenix Reisen</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2006</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>28,717</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating. Ex-Asuka</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Amant</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>PhoenixVoyages (Vietnam)</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2010</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Built in 2010 by a local Vietnamese shipyard (Vuotsong), L'Amant operates on the Mekong River in Vietnam, and is without any doubt the most well constructed vessel sailing in Vietnam.</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Oasis of the Seas</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean Cruise Line</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2009</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>225,282</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Andes</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Royal Mail Lines</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>1959</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>27,000</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Was liner, became cruise ship in 1959.</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Anna Nery</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Companhia de Navegacao Costeirab</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>1962</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Ended service in 1978. Currently operating as Salamis Glory</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>National Geographic Endeavour</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Lindblad Expeditions</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>1996</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating, also known as Endeavour</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Liberty of the Seas</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2007</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>154,407</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Norwegian Epic</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Norwegian Cruise Line</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2010</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>153,000</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Independence of the Seas</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2008</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>154,407</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Navigator of the Seas</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2002</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>  138,000</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td class="name"><div>Caribbean Princess</div></td>
            <td class="operator"><div>Princess Cruises</div></td>
            <td class="began"><div>2004</div></td>
            <td class="tonnage"><div>112,894</div></td>
            <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
          </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
      * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body {
    background:lightgray;
    margin:10px;
}
.fluid-width-and-height {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
  table.cruises { 
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    cellspacing: 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 535px;    
    }
  table.cruises td { 
    border-left: 1px solid #999; 
    border-top: 1px solid #999;  
    padding: 2px 4px;
    }
  table.cruises tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none;
  }
  table.cruises th { 
    border-left: 1px solid #999; 
    padding: 2px 4px;
    background: #6b6164;
    color: white;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    }
  table.cruises td { background: #eee; overflow: hidden; }

  div.scrollableContainer { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 592px; 
    padding-top: 2em; 
    margin: 40px;    
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #6b6164;
    }
  div.scrollingArea { 
    height: 240px; 
    overflow: auto; 
    }

  table.scrollable thead tr {
    left: -1px; top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    }

  table.cruises .name     div { width: 108px; }
  table.cruises .operator div { width: 126px; }
  table.cruises .began    div { width: 76px;  text-align:center; }
  table.cruises .tonnage  div { width: 60px;  text-align:center; }
  table.cruises .status   div { width: 160px; }

  table.cruises td.operator { background: #ebcb4d; }
  table.cruises td.tonnage  { background: white; }
  table.cruises td.name     { background: #C7E0C1; }  
  table.cruises td.began    { background: #B7C3E8; }
```

Comment: Don't set a fixed width and height for `table.cruises` and `div.scrollableContainer`

Comment: If it were only that easy... Removing the pixel widths don't help. See here where they are replaced with percentages: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvygQ/1 Notice how the thead no longer lines up with the tbody. And this still leaves the height issue.

Comment: I knew it wouldn't be that easy, but that's the immediate problem. Hardcoding widths/heights won't let anything expand properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Better suggestion... try using DataTables for JQuery (http://www.datatables.net)

---

You can use the CSS style "width" on the table and set it to 100%.

```
style="width:100%;"
```

The table will then be 100% width to the parent DIV container. Just make your DIVs as wide as you want them.

If you want your DIVs to stretch the width of the browser window you can try the same technique on the DIVs or look at the browser width and set the values dynamically. You can use javascript to get (and set) those values.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Comment: +1 I don't see the point in doing this with JavaScript when you can just do it properly with CSS. Though, putting it in a style tag is not necessary. You'd want to change the line that says `width: 535px;` in the stylesheet.

Comment: Also, you need to remove the `width: 535px;` from the `scrollableContainer`.

Comment: If it were only that easy...  Removing the pixel widths don't help.  See here where they are replaced with percentages:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZvygQ/1/  Notice how the thead no longer lines up with the tbody.  And this still leaves the height issue.